[safety and automation]: hydroxy auth for protonmail

I want to use mutt for protonmail
i saw that protonbridge-mail does not work for me,
and that hydroxide provides an alternative solution.

I installed hydroxide with the settings outlined here
Configure mutt and hydroxide for Protonmail
and it works. so, to be specific. I use



set ssl_starttls=no
set ssl_force_tls=no


i would like to understand exactly what is happening when I do


hydroxide auth myID@protonmail.com
and then I am forced to enter my protonmail password.


Is the connection safe?  is the password send out via encrypted means?

When I log into with correct password, Protonmail immediately sends me a warning
message:



New Login to myID@protonmail.com on Unknown. If this wasn't you, please change your password immediately.

(a) Protonmail does not recognize what device is logged in? why it is Unknown?
(b) Also, after correctly supplying my protonmail password in auth process, hydroxide then spits out another password, which it calls Bridge Password.
How is this Bridge Password generated? and how has hydroxide used my original Protonmail Password? Has that travelled over the net?
If this is actually secure, how do I automate the login process, without storing my protonmail password on my machine?
